# How to remove special accents of some language from table in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Tags: nlp, sas, enterprise-guide, 4gl, accent-sensitive

I have table in SAS like below:

```
col1
----------
AęŁź   
ABCóó
śdźcąę
...
```

Of course I have also many more columns in my table, but I need to remove accents from letters in above table , so as a result I need something like below:

```
col1
----------
AeLz 
ABCoo
sdzcae
...
```

How can I do that in SAS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `basechar()` function will get you there *most* of the way, but you may have a few leftover. You can take care of those manually with `tranwrd()`.

```
data want;
    set have;

    col1 = basechar(col1);
    col1 = tranwrd(col1, 'Ł', 'L');
run;
```

You can find all of the letters that are remaining with `compress`:

```
remaining = compress(col1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

Comment: Thank you Stu Sztukowski - as always best SAS expert :)